# standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory" on Windows

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile

I have a situation where I have codes stored in GitHub, a Jenkins Pipeline to clone repo and build a docker image. But when run the image I got the following error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

But I am able to create a docker image using my local directory and command line to build and run the images successfully.

Note: I am using Windows with Docker Desktop for Windows, and Jenkins installed

I expect to have the docker image to run as I expected using command line.

Comment: That's the same error one gets any other time one is trying to run a program that doesn't exist, or which requires an interpreter that doesn't exist. Please include enough details to allow someone to reproduce *your specific form of the error*, which hopefully isn't caused by a file just not being there.

Comment: Are you fully-qualifying your path to the executable to run? If not, what's the `PATH` in the process doing the execution? We don't want questions to include *irrelevant* details, but these are extremely relevant to the error at hand.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think I may have found the answer to this issue. I have included dos2unix in the Dockerfile and run it on my .sh file to convert to unix.

Answer (score 17):

It is because you checkout files from github in windows end of line style `\r\n`

You need manually convert EOL style to `\n` for all *.sh/*.bash files

Comment: October 2021! Still works. Went into my .sh and beautified code with pycharm shell script formatter

Answer (score 0):

This can also be because a dynamically linked library is missing from the image.